# ubuntu 18.04 brother-mfc7460dn

Tags: 18.04, printing, scanner, brother

my printer Brother MFC7460DN has worked fine with xubuntu 16.04. Since the upgrade to 18.04, the printer is not working anymore. I have reinstalled it, following the instructions according to Brother and also the suggestions here ( [Ubuntu 18.04 - Brother MFC7460DN printer / Scanner installation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1047873/ubuntu-18-04-brother-mfc7460dn-printer-scanner-installation?noredirect=1&lq=1) ), but without success.

The installation is working perfectly, the printer is recognised and it seems to receive test print jobs, but no printing. It may be a driver issue related to 18.04 . When I select another driver (MFC 7360 or sth), I manage to make a print job, but the print result is somehow garbage.

Has someone MFC7460DN running on 18.04, and how?

KR, Hartmut

Comment: The printer is working now. Maybe only a reboot was missing. So, false alarm, sorry.